# Selenium : Waiting till Progress bar process is completed in the UI (wait till for Progress bar might vary test to another test)

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, progress-bar, webautomation

I am using selenium for UI automation ,where i want to wait till a Progress bar is completed and after the Progress bar is completed i Want to perform some other action. I have tried WedDriverWait, Invisibility of element located but its not working . Please suggest some way to handle Progress bar using C#  Selenium.

I have Tried waitUntil Invisibility of element located function for the Particular Xpath

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(900000000));
                                wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath(buildProgressStringExp)));

string buildProgressStringExp = "//table[@class='pane stripped']/tbody//descendant::tr[@class='build-row transitive single-line overflow-checked']//table[@class='progress-bar ']"
```

[image: Progress bar and HTML DOM]

i have tried the below code but it still didnt work. Its waiting till a particular time limit after that its throwing exception

````
        {while(true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        IWebElement el = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("Xpath of bar"));
                        bool abc = el.GetAttribute("style").Equals("width:100%;");
                        if (abc)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                        catch(StaleElementReferenceException exp)
                    {
                            return true;
                        }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                }```
````

Comment: At the end of the build, some states will change on the screen, like the small circle will turn into red or green right? Or also that 'x' icon will go away, did you tried to use they as base for waiting?

Comment: Please take a minute to fix the indent on your code. Also, please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. The screenshot of the page is fine but the screenshot of HTML is not. You realize the time you are waiting is 28.5 years, right? That seems a bit silly, no?

Comment: @Spencer , at the end of the build the xpath for the first element changes and also the x icon disappear s. I tried with both but still not working.

Comment: @Jeff I will do that thnks for suggesting . I know the time I am waiting is too long and it's silly and also  it's a test code , but still with that wait time the driver is not waiting till the element disappear here the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the element is not meeting the criteria used by that expected condition. Below is the code for [InvisibilityOfElementLocated](https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras/blob/dc402a5d7b9d7e78a9ce293bdb64b0b9a47685d5/src/WaitHelpers/ExpectedConditions.cs#L360)

```
/// <summary>
/// An expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not present on the DOM.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="locator">The locator used to find the element.</param>
/// <returns><see langword="true"/> if the element is not displayed; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.</returns>
public static Func<IWebDriver, bool> InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)
{
    return (driver) =>
    {
        try
        {
            var element = driver.FindElement(locator);
            return !element.Displayed;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            // Returns true because the element is not present in DOM. The
            // try block checks if the element is present but is invisible.
            return true;
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            // Returns true because stale element reference implies that element
            // is no longer visible.
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

If the page does not change it will not go stale, if the search finds it but it is some hidden another way where display never returns false this will never work.

You may need to write you own func for this to work with your page.

Comment: Tanks Cain for responding , but these are build in functions , is there any way to update it ?

Comment: @Zoso619 I am not sure I follow. InvisibilityOfElementLocated is a existing method but you can write your own func for .Until to use which is specific to the conditions you are wanting for. Also anytime you use Wait.Until you are setting a max time after which an exception will be thrown. If the progress bar takes longer then x then the wait has failed.

Comment: Tried this , it did not work for me. Actually the driver is waiting for 5-6 mins before throwing Stale Element exception. Not sure why its not waiting till the bar invisible in the UI. Its waiting but not more than 5-6 mins . For the test case which takes longer duration getting failed .